# Compare two lists in Python with o(n) complexity

Tags: python, list

I have two lists and I want to find the keywords from the statements and if the statement has that particular keyword then I have to return that keyword.
I am doing this in `o(n^2)`. Can I do this in `o(n)` or in some other lesser complexity?

```
keywords = ['name', 'class', 'school', 'address']

statements = ['name is hello', 'name is not hello', 'school is hello', 'address is hello']

for key in keywords :
    for statement in statements :
            string = statement
            if string.find(key) != -1:
            print(key)
```

We can increase the space complexity if we want to but I need to decrease the time complexity. I just need a logic through which I can achieve this.

Comment: Why is there a `return`?

Comment: Just a pseudo code, you can consider print statement there. Please suggest some logic.

Comment: Are you comparing them in order, i.e. keywords[0] vs statements[0], keywords[1] vs statements[1] etc?

Comment: No, all the statements need to be compared with all the keywords.

Answer (score 1):

Make your list of keywords a set. That way, if you want to check whether a word is a keyword, it's O(1) lookup. (If you care about space complexity, then use a [radix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree) instead)

```
words = {'name', 'class', ...}
```

Then iterate through each word in your statements like so:

```
for statement in statements:
    for word in statement.split():
        if word in words:
            print(word)
```

`O(n * m)`, where `m` is the length of the longest string. I'm not sure how efficient `str.split()` is or how it exactly works, but you could reduce the space complexity here by finding each word manually by going through `statement` and checking for spaces, instead of creating a list in memory.

Comment: But here also there are two for loops, doesn't this mean it'll give a complexity of o(n^2) ?

Comment: @user Two for-loops does not necessarily mean O(n^2). In this case, `n` is not the same length of each for loop. `n` is the length of the outer for-loop (number of items in `statements`, and `m` is the (maximum) length of the inner for-loop (number of words in a `statement`)

Comment: i tried this with my code but still the complexity is almost o(n^2). Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to find if *any* key in keywords exists in *any* statements, try using `str.join` first:

```
joined_statements = ' '.join(statements)
for key in keywords:
    if key in joined_statements:
        print(key)
```

Output:

```
name
school
address
```

Comment: This code will give a generalized answer. It wont tell which statement had that keyword. I needed that as well.

Comment: `in` will be O(n). See here -> https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity (x in s)

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing

> if string.find(key) != -1:

you can just do

if key in string:

But anyways the indentation is wrong and that return shouldn't work anyways.

instead you could do something like this:

```html
keywords = ['name', 'class', 'school', 'address']
checkedkeywords = []

statements = ['name is hello', 'name is not hello', 'school is hello', 'address is hello']

for key in keywords :
    for statement in statements :
            string = statement
            if key in string:
              checkedkeywords.append(key)

print(checkedkeywords)
```

Hope it helps and good luck!

Comment: Still this is in o(n^2) complexity.

Answer (score 0):

So, you need to use REVERSE INDEXING approach to solve this problem.

Create an empty dictionary, `lookup_dict={}`

Now loop through each word in each statements and store the STATEMENTS_INDEX corresponding to that word as described below.

`statements = ['name is hello', 'name is not hello', 'school is hello', 'address is hello']`

```
lookup_dict= {
          'name': [0,1], # Denoting 'name' keyword comes in index 0 and 1
          'is': [0,1,2,3],
          'hello':[0,1,2,3],
          'not':[1],
          'address':[3]
 }
```

Now, once u create your indexes, which is usually a one time operation, if there is a hell lot of data.

Now if you need to check which keyword comes in which all statements, Just use the lookup dictionary.

Suppose now u need to check what all statements does the keyword *name* came in, just lookup in dictionary and you will get all the indexes.

This logic is called reverse indexing and is used by lucene which is used by solr, elasticsearch internally.

Comment: this is feasible only if the records are less and there are limited words in the statements. otherwise this itself will take a lot of time and then searching of unnecessary words like "is" "the" "of" etc will also be a burden.

Answer (score -1):

You need this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm 
Find string in another string it not free.
More easy way

```
keywords = ['name', 'class', 'school', 'address']

statements = ['name is hello', 'name is not hello', 'school is hello', 'address is hello']
from collection import defaultdict
word2statements = defaultdict(list)
for statement in statements :
    for word in set(statement.split()):
        word2statements[word].append(statement)

for keyword in keywords:
    word2statements[keyword]
```

Comment: The complexity is still o(n^2)

Comment: O(numbers of words in statements + len(keywords))